# SSH to droplet with non root user

Tags: ssh

I recently made some new users in my digitalocean droplet, and I would like to access them directly with the command `ssh username@ip`. However, I get denied with `username@ip: Permission denied (publickey)`. For clarification, the machine has the correct private-key and can access the droplet with `ssh root@ip`

I did the following to create the new user

```
root@school:~# adduser username
Adding user `username' ...
Adding new group `username' (1001) ...
Adding new user `username' (1001) with group `username' ...
Creating home directory `/home/username' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
```

After these steps, what is further to do to be able to access the droplet with `ssh username@ip` ?

Comment: if available you could use the tool ssh-copy-id username@ip to copy the PUBLIC key to the authorized_key file from the user on the server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *"the machine has the correct private-key"*

That is the root cause of your misunderstanding. Access is controlled separately for **each account**, not for the machine as a whole.

For each account you want to access with a particular key you will need to append the associated public key to the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`  in the home directory of that account.

Or in other words: copy `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` to `/home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys` and ensure the correct ownership and permissions on those files/directories.

Comment: while true please note that you will copy the PUBLIC key, not the private key into the authorized_keys.
Additionally copy might just overwrite and give too much access so be catious when doing a copy.

Comment: It would be simpler using the ssh-copy-id tool:
`ssh-copy-id user@remote-host`

Comment: @JucaPirama `ssh-copy-id user@remote-host` leaves you in a bit of a catch-22 when your SSHD configuration does not allow password authentication (which is quite strongly recommended).

Comment: can you confirm if I should do ```ssh-copy-id``` from my local computer or the from the first account (that can already ssh) on the remote server?

Comment: @Nesha25  When you have the password for the user account and password authentication is not disabled in the sshd_config , then by all means run `ssh-copy-id` from your local computer to populate the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys ` file for your user on the remote server. AFAIK the `ssh-copy-id` only adds public keys for which the private keys are available to the script and can't be used to copy public keys between accounts .